# How to ignore files that begin with 2 letters in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a condition in my VBA code that will only search in files with names that do not begin with 2 letters. The user will select a folder and all files in the folder will be searched UNLESS the filename starts with any combination of 2 letters.

I.E. If I had these files in a selected folder:

22A.xls

2B2.xls

C2D.xls

EF2.xls

I want every file analyzed except for the "EF2.xls" file. The filenames will vary so I need it to ignore all filenames where the 2 starting characters are both letters.

Answer (score 4):

1. Use `Dir` to loop over the files in the folder.
2. Test if the left two characters of the file name are letters using `Like "[A-z][A-z]*"`. If not, then proceed.

```vb
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print Not "22A.xls" Like "[A-z][A-z]*" ' returns True
    Debug.Print Not "2B2.xls" Like "[A-z][A-z]*" ' returns True
    Debug.Print Not "C2D.xls" Like "[A-z][A-z]*" ' returns True
    Debug.Print Not "EF2.xls" Like "[A-z][A-z]*" ' returns False
End Sub
```